# Can any one briefly describe what this => operator in linq and its work

Tags: c#, linq

```
using (var ctx = new SchoolDBEntities())
    {    
        var student = ctx.Students.Where(s => s.StudentName == "Bill")
                      .FirstOrDefault<Student>();
    }
```

Can any one briefly describe what this => operator in linq and its work..

Comment: Its a lambda and has nothing to do with linq.

Comment: it's just an operator that identifies a lambda expression/statement called _"goes to"_ operator. nothing more.

Comment: refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions

Comment: The '=>' is the lambda operator here; there are two different syntaxs for creating LINQ queries and this is the syntax for performing a lambda LINQ query. For what you posted it's saying I'm going to perform operations on the elements in Students and I'm going to refer to one of these individual elements as 's'. So get all of the Students where the StudentName is "Bill" and then select the first of these (or any empty string default if there are none).

Comment: The other syntax for LINQ queries reads more like backwards SQL - you can see examples here: 

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Restriction-Operators-b15d29ca#WhereSimple1

And here someone has translated those examples to use the lambda expression syntax

http://linq101.nilzorblog.com/restriction-operators.php#where-simple-1

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a shorter variant of an function/lambda definition. This do all the same:

```
var v1 = ctx.Students.Where((Student s) => { return s.StudentName == "Bill"; }).FirstOrDefault<Student>();
var v2 = ctx.Students.Where((Student s) => s.StudentName == "Bill").FirstOrDefault<Student>();
var v3 = ctx.Students.Where(s => s.StudentName == "Bill").FirstOrDefault<Student>();
// You could skip the Where and do the filtering in FirstOrDefault directly
var v4 = ctx.Students.FirstOrDefault<Student>(s => s.StudentName == "Bill");
var v5 = ctx.Students.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StudentName == "Bill");
```

[MSDN: Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx)
[MSDN: FirstOrDefault Overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039(v=vs.110).aspx)
Also have a look at the link `imgprasad` posted...